# Why would directly connecting (hard wire) to router not work on a Mac but wi-fi is ok?

Tags: router

I recently got CenturyLink DSL and they gave me an ActionTec C1000A router that has 4 ports and is also wireless. I want to use both wired (for my main computer)and wireless (for iphones/roku etc..) but the wired port only works on a PC. My MAC Mini Server can only use the wi-fi and I'm stumped.

I can see the Mac does connect to the network when wired, but when i navigate to a web page, it times out and I get a 'can't connect to DNS' error. My PC acts as expected when hard wired.

Has anyone seen this happen on Mac OSX 10.8.3 or suggest things I can try to fix this? CenturyLink was no help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question:

> 'can't connect to DNS'

Go to network settings and try adding ether DNS from DHCP or Google's DNSes:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

Comment: You would not believe how many hours I've wasted on this issue... and money! Was tricked into signing up for a tech help service that masked as official Apple Help, tried for hours to do this myself, bleeding routers etc.. And you just helped me fix it in five minutes. THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!